# SQL Server - Row added via parent table trigger not available in child table trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, dependencies, foreign-key-relationship, constraints

I have 3 tables

1. `ParentTable`
2. `ChildTable` (with column `ParentId` refering to `ParentTable`)
3. `Recording` (with column `ParentId` refering to own table)

Parent table has a trigger which adds a row into the `Recording` table.

Child table again has a trigger that appends row in `Recording` table

Now I get an error that the row was not found in `Recording` table

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE
>   constraint

Comment: Add in your question the tables' and the triggers' definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be triggering a duplicate ParentID to be inserted into the Recording table. This would be true if your ParentID in the Recording table has a unique key defined on it.

When inserting into the Parent table, you insert a record with a ParentID into Recording. I think your insert a duplicate ParentID on the ChildTable trigger.

Maybe you can provide some more context.

Also, you might want to avoid triggers if possible - which it is most of the time. Using CTE's and OUTPUT clauses this can help you avoid issues with triggers.

Comment: Disagree strongly with the advice to avoid triggers. There are many times when that is the best way to ensure data integrity.

Comment: @HLGEM Triggers has their place, but there are better ways to enforce integrity than triggers. When you are working with nested transactions and lots of data, triggers become a pain from a maintenance point of view. There are also a lot of scenarios where rollbacks can also cause integrity issues. MS is moving away from triggers and best practices all over is to start doing the same. With well coded CTE's, you don't need anything else to enforce your integrity.

Comment: Just for clarity - I'm not strongly opposing triggers, only saying try to avoid them. If systems are largely dependant on triggers, keep them there. But for anything new, there is Always a better answer than triggers - if your are on SQL 2008 and higher.